# Is there any way to append a Node after HTML closing tag </html>?

Tags: javascript

I need to append a node **after** html closing tag `</html>`
I tried a lot of document functions but nothing works else `createComment()`

```
document.appendChild(document.createComment('Comment'));
```

anything else show this error message:

```
Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed
```

**Note:** I tried to work around this by using `removeChild()` to remove HTML tag with its full contents and then used `document.write()` to insert a new `<html>...</html>` with a new tag appended to it, and it works fine but the browser sanitized it and my new tag moved inside `<body>`.

So, Is there any way to append a Node **after** HTML closing tag `</html>`?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? [From the W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.3): "an HTML document is contained [entirely] by the HTML element"

Comment: i need to do that to make tests and debug my script.

Comment: Not sure what tests you're attempting to run, but it's invalid HTML to have nodes outside the `HTML` tag. @Adelin's answer dives a bit more in-depth, but this won't be possible in Javascript.

Comment: Perhaps someone can suggest you an alternative if you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve by adding this element.

Comment: "i need to do that to make tests and debug my script." — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem — It seems unlikely that you need to do this in order to write tests or perform debugging.

Comment: @al-dr — If you want public help then you have to make public enough information for people to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the official html reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/semantics.html#the-html-element), the `<html>` element:

- represents **the root of an HTML document**.
- contains a head element followed by a body element

This is its definition, shortly.
That means that no node can exist outside of it.

The only possible way to add that is by inspecting the entire page, and manually adding it, but the attempt will be short lived, because the input will get sanitized by the browser.

A [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#) would throw a `Stray start tag` type of error.
You can play around here to check what is a correct, accepted syntax and what not: https://html5.validator.nu/

And since you tagged the question [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), it's definitely not possible in js.
JS represents the parent element of the html element as `null`. If it wouldn't, maybe you had a chance, but that is a big *if*

```
document.documentElement.parentElement === null
```

So, in short, **no**, it is not possible

Comment: thank you very much Adelin, i tried to work around it by using removeChild() to remove html tag with its contents and then used document.write to insert a new <html>...</html> with a new tag appended to it, and it works fine but as you said the browser sanitized it.

Comment: "The tag tells the browser that this is an HTML document" — It doesn't. The Content-Type HTTP response header does.

Comment: "The tag represents the root of an HTML document." — It doesn't. The HTML element represents that. The html start tag just marks the start of that element.

Comment: "except for the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag" — The document type declaration is not a tag.

Comment: Don't trust W3Schools. It is awful.